# Compile error at creating a queue using list

Tags: java, compilation, queue

My project requires i make a FIFO queue using a list and i have to create simple methods to put, remove and return objects etc. But when i compile the following code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

class IntQueueImpl  { 

public int size;
private Node head, tail; 
private class Node { 
    int item; 
    Node next; 
    Node(int item) { 
        this.item = item; 
        next = null; }
        } 

IntQueueImpl(int max) { 
    head = null; tail = null; 
    }


public boolean isEmpty() { 
    return (head == null); 
    }

    public void put(int item) { 
    Node t = tail; 
    tail = new Node(item); 
    if (isEmpty()) head = tail; 
    else t.next = tail;
    size++;
    } 


public int get() throws NoSuchElementException;{ 
    if ( isEmpty() ) 
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
    int v = head.item; 
    Node t = head.next; 
    head = t; 
    return v;

    } 

    public int peek() throws NoSuchElementException{
    if ( isEmpty() ){ 
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    int peekelement =head.item;
    return peekelement;
    } 


    public int size(){

    if(isEmpty()) return 0;

    else return size;

    }

}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
 IntQueueImpl.java:35: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
    public int get() throws NoSuchElementException;{
               ^
 IntQueueImpl.java:41: error: return outside method
            return v;
```

and i have to clue what it means or how to fix it....

Comment: you have a semicolon in `public int get() throws NoSuchElementException;{ ` before { brace. Remove that.

Answer (score 1):

On line 34,  you have:

```
public int get() throws NoSuchElementException;{
```

Remove that semicolon, and see if that fixes your compiler errors:

```
public int get() throws NoSuchElementException {
```

Answer (score 1):

How about removing ';'? in public "int get() throws NoSuchElementException;{"